# Silverlight Out Of Browser Laucher has Stopped Working

Tags: silverlight

We are running Silverlight 4 version Web Application same in Silverlight Out Of Browser App but when in Out Of Browser crashes

continuously after some time usage getting message as "Silverlight Out Of Browser Laucher has Stopped Working " and crashes. We have checked Memory usage and it having 530 MB and CPU Usage is 40%.

Is this causing due to any Silverlight plugin issue ? . where as in IE same application works better than OOB app and it crashes rarely but OOB app it crashes continuously . Earlier we have memory leak issue and fixed by implementing proper garbage collection techniques in Dispose method. so its not due memory leak and somethign causes in OOB app that crashes.

Can you any one suggest some possible solutions to avoid following crashing issue or can trace where might causing this issue ?  As it is Out of Browser app we cant see page errors . Please suggest some tracing techniques.

Thanks

Krishna[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Following IE crashing logs got

Comment: Do the crashes happen only on touch-enabled devices by any chance?